# Best way to export large chunks of data

Tags: angularjs, json, xml, excel, csv

I am working in angularjs . I want to export many thousands of records from the database. The aim is to export and import also the data in the best and fastest way possible.

I have done some R&D and found that few of the available options are excel , flat files, json , xml.

Now I am bit confused which is the best option to integrate with angularjs and will give the best results in terms of time for export, time for import and in terms of code complexity .

Answer (score 0):

The use of json would be great because angularjs have a built-in handler for json which allow you to serialize json into js object and vice versa.

Hope this help !

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. If using json format, If I have 20 columns and around 20 thousand rows, then as json is key value pair  so, for every row the 20 column names would be repeated?

Comment: @Tarun yes, but data can be zipped, so my suggestion is to use 'zipped' json for import-export. Another solution can be the evergreen csv (aka flat files) that doesn't have column name redundancy

Comment: It's up to you to format the json as you want but yes basically the 20 column names will be repeated.

Comment: As @DDS says csv will solve column name redundancy but you have to serialize it yourself.